# Access modem from different subnet locally, remotely

Tags: networking, router, modem

The topology is as follows :

Modem(192.168.100.1) > Router(192.168.1.1)

Router has a ddns so I can access offsite, and I can port forward if I want to access various network offsite.

How do I access the modem, from its subnet, offsite through the router?

I suspect this is done with static routes, but do not know how to implement with this router...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the model of modem.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be not to expose the modem to the internet, and simply access it via a RDP or VNC Session from a machine running within the network.

If you use sensible passwords, and ensure the in-network machine is up to date, it would maintain your network security.

---

That said, I believe it would be possible to do this by port forwarding from the router to the modem.

I would suggest translating a different port (something outside the standard range) to whatever port the modem uses, to give a vague sense of security (by obscurity)

Comment: I know there is a better way of doing this.  I am asking in particular because I would like to monitor customers modems, en masse.  With cable modems, while they are bridged, you can still access at the 192.168.100.1.  It would not be feasible to have a pc at every location.